# var debug = require('debug')('express:router:route'); TypeError: require(...) is not a function /

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
var debug = require('debug')('express:router:route');
                        ^
TypeError: require(...) is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/net/My_dir/JAVASCRPIT/my js/js codes/Backend/Intermediate Express_3/PostRequestDemo/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:16:29)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:692:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/net/My_dir/JAVASCRPIT/my js/js codes/Backend/Intermediate Express_3/PostRequestDemo/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:16:13)
```

Comment: Could you please edit your question to include your own code as well? :)

Comment: Is this the same issue as before? [Hello guys, whenever I try to run app.js through node, I keep on getting this eror! Help please! TypeError: require(...) is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60695445/hello-guys-whenever-i-try-to-run-app-js-through-node-i-keep-on-getting-this-er) If so - please include details in your question so we can help!